# Windows batch echo countdown

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, variables, count, command

I have a script with a for loop that works but I would like to change the echoed line so that it includes the number of retries remaining.

Below is my latest attempt but I cannot get it to show the number of retries:

```
rem Will loop 20 times with 30 second intervals (Total 10 minutes) to confirm deletion. Loop will exit after 20 attempts and move on if dll cannot be deleted.
for /l %%i in (1,1,20) do (
set /a "count=20-=%%i"
del /f /q "%Folder2Del%file*.dll" >nul
if not exist "%Folder2Del%file*.dll" goto Folder2Del
echo/
echo File locked! Will try to delete %count% more times before exit.
timeout /t 30 >nul
)
```

I've searched and tried to apply many examples but I just can't get it working. I don't know how to properly set my 'count' variable.

Comment: you would need `delayedexpansion`

Comment: [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)

Comment: and `set /a "count=20-=%%i"` is wrong. It should read `set /a count=20-%%i`. alternatively you could `for /l %%i in (20,-1,1) do (` and just `echo ...try to delete %%i more times...` (no need for the `count` variable, so also no need for delayed expansion)

Comment: @Stephan - The latter works perfectly. Thanks!